# Magit version post-installation does not look as in the manual

Tags: magit

I have just installed Magit from Melpa as per [the instructions in the official Magit manual](https://magit.vc/manual/magit.html#Installing-from-an-Elpa-Archive). I then proceeded to follow the manual's [Post-Installation Tasks](https://magit.vc/manual/magit.html#Post_002dInstallation-Tasks) section, which states

> After installing Magit you should verify that you are indeed using the Magit, Git, and Emacs releases you think you are using. [...]
>
> `M-x magit-version RET`
>
> should display something like
>
> `Magit 2.8.0, Git 2.10.2, Emacs 25.1.1, gnu/linux`

The results of my running `M-x magit-version RET` are

> `Magit 20170401.1145, Git (unknown), Emacs 25.1.1, darwin`

This doesn't seem to match the expected output.

1. The Magit version number doesn't have the expected format.
2. Git does not have a version number at all.

Is this a problem? If so, what should I do to fix it?

---

**Attempted Steps**

1. **Is Git installed on my system?** Opening a Terminal window and running `git --version` yields `git version 2.10.1`. In particular, **Git is installed on my system**.
2. **Are the Git executables on emacs' `PATH`?** Evaluating `(getenv "PATH")` in emacs yields a string that starts with `/usr/bin`. Opening a Terminal window and running `ls /usr/bin` brings up a list that includes `git`. So **the Git executables are on emacs' `PATH`**.
3. **Are the Git executables on emacs' `exec-path`?** Checking the value of emacs' `exec-path` variable by entering `C-h v exec-path RET` in emacs yields a string that starts with `"/usr/bin"`, so **the Git executables are on emacs' `exec-path`**.
4. **Maybe the Git executables that the shell uses are in a different place than `/usr/bin/`. Try running `which git` from a Terminal window.** I ran `which git` from a Terminal window, and indeed the result was different to `/usr/bin/`, namely `/usr/local/bin/`. So I added the following lines of code to my `.emacs` file:

   `(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/bin/"))`
   `(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin/")))`

   and restarted Emacs, but the problem remained. So, **yes, the Git executables that the shell uses are indeed in a different place, but appending the correct location to the end of `PATH`/`exec-path` has no effect.**
5. **If appending to `PATH`/`exec-path` doesn't do the trick, how about prepending?** I added the following lines of code to my `.emacs` file:

   `(setenv "PATH" (concat "/usr/local/bin/:" (getenv "PATH")))`
   `(setq exec-path (append '("/usr/local/bin/") exec-path))`

   and **now it works!**
6. **An alternative solution:** Taking a lead from a comment by npostavs below, I installed Xcode from the Apple store, restarted my computer (not sure this step was necessary; I decided to do this on my own), and ran `sudo xcodebuild -license` from a Terminal window to accept Xcode's license agreement. Now Magit works even without modifying Emac's `PATH` and `exec-path`, and also the Git version is more up-to-date (it was `2.10.1` before; now it's `2.11.0 (Apple Git-81)`).

   The downside is that Xcode takes a big chunk of memory (4.53 GB), it has received many very bad reviews on the Apple store, I had to sign a license agreement with Apple, and aside from the convenience of not having to modify the Emacs path for Magit to work, I have no use for this mammoth, since I'm not an Apple developer.

---

Operating system: macOS Sierra, Version 10.12.4
Emacs version: 25.1.1

Comment: How does the output of `/usr/local/bin/git --version` differ from `/usr/bin/git --version`?

Comment: (In case it's not clear, your code in (4) is appending to `PATH`/`exec-path` but you need to **pre**pend.)

Comment: @npostavs: `/usr/local/bin/git --version` yields `git version 2.10.1`, whereas `/usr/bin/git --version` yields `xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun`.

Comment: @npostavs: Yes, you were right! Prepending rather than appending did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: http://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/10/01/xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path-library-developer-commandline-tools-missing-xcrun/ could be relevant (or you can just keep using the git from `/usr/local/bin`, not clear to me what the difference is)

Comment: By the way, the `(push ...)` suggested by tarsius is pretty much just a more concise way of prepending (for `exec-path` that is; for `PATH` what you have is fine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Magit version number doesn't have the expected format.

All version numbers on Melpa (non-stable) are just timestamps. So this is expected. But this [might be changed eventually](https://github.com/melpa/melpa/issues/2955).

> Git does not have a version number at all.

That could mean that Magit is not able to find any `git` executable, which of course would be a big problem.

If you are actually able to use Magit, then please post the output of `git version`, because another possibility is that it prints something we did not expect.

---

> Progress, at last! Hurrah! What now?

We have established that I was right all along. Your shell is configured correctly to use the `git` that you have installed, but that configuration does not carry over to an Emacs instance that was started by clicking on an icon. The reason for this is that Emacs does not read your shell's configuration files, which makes sense because it is a different application.

You now have to customize Emacs to use the same `git` executable by configuring `exec-path` correctly. There are multiple ways of doing that and doing it by hand is what I recommend. Based on the information you have provided I would assume that `(push "/usr/local/bin" exec-path)` should do the trick.

Another option would be to configure Emacs'`exec-path` based on your shell's configuration, even when Emacs isn't started from a shell by using the [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) package.

Comment: It turns out I didn't have git installed on my system. So I went ahead and installed it. Now when I enter `git --version` in a Terminal window I receive the following output: `git version 2.10.1`. However, when I run `M-x magit-version` on emacs I still get `Git (unknown)`.

Comment: Just a random guess, but you probably installed it using homebrew and can use it on the command line because your shell's `$PATH` has been adjusted accordingly. However you start Emacs by clicking on an icon and so environment variables that you set in your shell's init file do not apply. You have to tell Emacs where homebrew installs executable by adding an element to `exec-path`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by homebrew. I installed Git from [this page](https://git-scm.com/download/mac). It is true that I don't invoke emacs from the command line. Where can I find out where the Git executables are?

Comment: Running `(getenv "PATH")` in emacs yields a string that starts with `/usr/bin`. Opening a Terminal window and running `ls /usr/bin` brings up a list that includes `git`.

Comment: `(getenv "PATH")` does not really matter here. Check the value of `exec-path` instead.

Comment: Checking the value of emacs' `exec-path` variable by entering `C-h v exec-path RET` in emacs yields a string that starts with `"/usr/bin"`, so the Git executables are on emacs' `exec-path`.

Comment: Does the shell command `which git` respond with `/usr/bin/git` ? If you *do* start emacs from a shell rather than your GUI launcher, does Magit work?

Comment: @phils: The shell command `which git` responds with `/usr/local/bin`. So I added lines to my `.emacs` file to append this directory to both `PATH` and `exec-path`. I then restarted emacs and ran `M-x magit-version` again, but it still reports `Git (unknown)`.

Comment: @phils: As for starting emacs from the shell: I've never done this before. How do you do it?

Comment: Just type the command `emacs` at the shell prompt. Unless OSX installs it somewhere which is not in your PATH, that should work.

Comment: @phils: When I start emacs from a shell (i.e. type `emacs` at a Terminal window), then run `M-x magit-version RET`, I get a `[No match]` message, i.e. the mini-buffer looks like this: `M-x magit-version [No match]`.

Comment: @phils: I should mention that I also get the following error message immediately after Terminal Emacs starts: `An error has occurred while loading '/Users/EvanAad/.emacs': Symbol's function definition is void: package-initialize To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the cause of the error in your initialization file. Start Emacs with
the '--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.`

Comment: This is an ancient version of emacs that came preinstalled with macOS. To find out where the version of emacs that you installed is, start it by clicking on the icon and then evaluate `(expand-file-name invocation-name invocation-directory)`. Then post that into a shell.

Comment: @phils: OK, I've run the correct Emacs executable from the command line, and then run `M-x magit-version RET` and got the correct result: `Magit 20170401.1145, Git 2.10.1, Emacs 25.1.1, darwin`. Progress, at last! Hurrah! What now?

Comment: Thanks, tarsius! Everything works now. FYI, I've now changed the previous step #5 to a new one, so you might want to change the last part of your answer accordingly.