# Uninstalling a package and all of its dependencies

Tags: package

Magit doesn't work on my system. I'd like to remove it and everything that came with it when I installed the package. How can I do this? What packages, beside Magit, were installed on my emacs when I installed Magit?

Comment: How did you install Magit?

Comment: @xuchunyang: Through emacs' package manager, via MELPA.

Comment: @Dan: Nothing, so far, because I don't want to break dependencies. First I'd like to know what got installed on my system along with Magit,

Comment: If you have not done so, I would highly recommend that you report the problem you are having with Magit, as it may well be solvable.

Comment: @phils: [I did report it](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31868/magit-version-post-installation-does-not-look-as-in-the-manual). Has not been solved.

Comment: You might want to give others more time than a single day to figure out what is wrong on you system.

Comment: @tarsius: I have indeed been giving it another chance, and now some progress seems to have been made. But it's still not completely resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Through emacs' package manager, via MELPA.

In which case a manual approach is:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `rgrep` <kbd>RET</kbd> `package-requires` <kbd>RET</kbd> `*.el` <kbd>RET</kbd> `~/.emacs.d/elpa/` <kbd>RET</kbd>

That will show you the dependencies for all your packages.

<kbd>C-s</kbd> `magit` <kbd>RET</kbd> to check that one, and you can then look for sub-dependencies in turn.

If an earlier version of Magit had a dependency that was removed in subsequent versions, it's possible that it would now be an 'orphaned' package, as I suspect package.el doesn't attempt to detect such things.  If you were really keen, and assuming you version-control your config, you could always check the dependencies over your repo history to see whether any such thing had occurred.

(Of course if you version-control your config, you almost certainly have a version-control record of what else you added when you installed or updated Magit.)

Comment: See `package-autoremove` for "orphaned packages" (requires Emacs 25.1+)