# Error running Emacs from a Terminal window: "Symbol's function definition is void: package-initialize"

Tags: init-file, osx, shell

After starting Emacs from a Terminal window, the following message is displayed:

```
An error has occurred while loading '/Users/EvanAad/.emacs':
Symbol's function definition is void: package-initialize
To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with the
'--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

Restarting Emacs with the `--debug-init` option displays the following in Emacs' Debugger buffer:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function package-initialize)
(package-initialize)   eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil
"/Users/evanaad/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading$
load-with-code-conversion("/Users/evanaad/.emacs"
"/Users/evanaad/.emacs"$   load("~/.emacs" t t)   #[nil
"^H\205\276^@   \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202A^@
\311=\2033^@\312\307\31$   command-line()   normal-top-level()
```

P.S. The reason why I want to start emacs from the command line is as an attempt to resolve [this issue](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31868/magit-version-post-installation-does-not-look-as-in-the-manual) (see step #5 in the 'Attempted steps' section).

---

Operating system: macOS Sierra, Version 10.12.4
Emacs version: 25.1.1

Comment: Running `emacs --version` from the shell will undoubtedly tell you a different version number to 25.1.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an ancient version of `emacs` that came preinstalled with macOS. To find out where the version of `emacs` that you installed is, start it by clicking on the icon and then evaluate `(expand-file-name invocation-name invocation-directory)`.

Then post that into a shell.

Comment: Scoffed at this answer at first, only to realize it was the correct one about 15 minutes of fruitless hacking later. Basically, `package-initialize` must have been added at some point later so the ancient one can't find that function. For some reason (probably CopyLeft restrictions), MacOS High Sierra (released 2017) ships with ```GNU Emacs 22.1.1
Copyright (C) 2007```